# iPhone regain ui focus to window after overlaying another view

Tags: ios, window, overlay

Am overlaying a view on the main windows like this:

```
    UIWindow *keyWindow = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window];
    [actionSheet showInView: keyWindow];
```

Which works fine and takes the UI Focus, the main window goes darker.

Removing the overlay like this

```
    [actionSheet removeFromSuperview];
    actionSheetVSTags = nil;
```

The action sheet goes away fine, but the main window does not have input focus (stays dark)

Have tried some of the window methods like

```
    UIWindow *keyWindow = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window];
    [keyWindow setWindowLevel: UIWindowLevelNormal];
    [keyWindow makeKeyAndVisible];
```

etc.

How to get the main windows to get UI focus again?

Yes, there are reasons for my madness here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To dismiss the actionSheet programmatically you should use the following method:

```
[actionSheet dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:buttonIndex animated:animated];
```

This is the same method that the action sheet automatically calls when you press one of the buttons you've had setup in it. If you have setup a delegate it will call:

```
– actionSheet:willDismissWithButtonIndex:
```

before removing itself and then

```
– actionSheet:didDismissWithButtonIndex:
```

after.

[UIActionSheet Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIActionSheet_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIActionSheet/dismissWithClickedButtonIndex%3aanimated%3a)